# Python - find a substring between two strings based on the last occurence of the later string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to find a substring which is between to strings. The first string is `<br>` and the last string is `<br><br>`. The first string I look for is repetitive, while the later string can serve as an anchor.

Here is an example:

```html
<div class="linkTabBl" style="float:left;padding-top:6px;width:240px">
    Anglo American plc
    <br>
    20 Carlton                 House Terrace
    <br>
    SW1Y 5AN London
    <br>
    United Kingdom
    <br><br>
    Phone : +44 (0)20 7968 8888
    <br>
    Fax : +44 (0)20 7968 8500
    <br>
    Internet : 
    <a class="pageprofil_link_blue" href="http://www.angloamerican.com" target="_blank">
        http://www.angloamerican.com
    </a>
    <br>
</div>
```

I am trying to get "United Kingdom". I would love to get this string with string manipulation but as well would be intesrted if anyone can get it with  Beautifulsoup (ideally using css_selector).

All the best.

[Web page](https://www.marketscreener.com/ANGLO-AMERICAN-PLC-4007113/company/)

Comment: You can maybe try doing a `split` and use `<br>` as the delimiter. Then look for the 4th (index 3) element.

Comment: I did but it is not always at the same place. I would really like to have an answer using the last anchor<br><br>, I guess i should split it there fist. But is any other way to do it let me know. Thank vm

Comment: Why not select the appropriate div with BeatifulSoup, then apply the correct regular expression on its `innerHTML`?

Comment: Will it always be above phone number at least?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi html shown is from selecting the appropriate <div>.
    my_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_source, 'lxml')
    css_selector = '.pageprofil_link_blue'
    my_tag:Tag = my_soup.select_one(css_selector)
    parent_tag = my_tag.parent
    print("parent div tag is:", parent_tag)

Comment: @MattCremeens, I think so, but would rather be safe using the <br><br> mark that I have noticed to be there all the times (for now anyway).

Comment: You could maybe `split` on `<br><br>` and then look at the first element of that `split` and then `split` that one on `<br>` and get the last element of that `split`.

Comment: If you have the HTML inside that div as string, try running the following regex on it:  
`/([^>]+)\s*<br>\s*<br>/.exec(innerHTML);`. The match should be the second element in the array that results from that.

Comment: @MattCremeens that worked:    my_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_source, 'lxml')
    css_selector = '.pageprofil_link_blue'
    my_tag:Tag = my_soup.select_one(css_selector)
    parent_tag = my_tag.parent
    print("parent div tag is:", parent_tag)
    print("parent div tag type:", type(parent_tag))
    split_address = str(parent_tag).split(sep='<br/><br/>')[0]
    split_address_list = str(split_address).split('<br/>')
    country = split_address_list[len(split_address_list)-1]
    print('country is:', country)

Comment: @admin: I will follow up on who minus the question since all answers I found were based on the first occurrence and not the latter. Very annoying to have people minusing whithout bringing answer or even darring to explain.... I would have loved a duplicate question as an explanation but he couldn't find it....

Comment: Can't be done with css because css never considers text nodes. With xpath it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

html = """<div class="linkTabBl" style="float:left;padding-top:6px;width:240px">
    Anglo American plc
    <br>
    20 Carlton                 House Terrace
    <br>
    SW1Y 5AN London
    <br>
    United Kingdom
    <br><br>
    Phone : +44 (0)20 7968 8888
    <br>
    Fax : +44 (0)20 7968 8500
    <br>
    Internet : 
    <a class="pageprofil_link_blue" href="http://www.angloamerican.com" target="_blank">
        http://www.angloamerican.com
    </a>
    <br>
</div>"""

res = re.findall(r'<br>\n    ([a-zA-Z\s]+)?\n    <br><br>', html)

print(res)
```

**Note:** *"\n    "* is a new line and 4 spaces from <'br'> to what you are looking for to <'br'> again. So if you have something like this:

```
...
<br>United Kingdom<br><br>
...
```

You should replace

`res = re.findall(r'<br>\n    ([a-zA-Z\s]+)?\n    <br><br>', html)`

by

`res = re.findall(r'<br>([a-zA-Z\s]+)?<br><br>', html)`

Good regex lessons here https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can get this using regex and the string of the html.

```py
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.marketscreener.com/ANGLO-AMERICAN-PLC-4007113/company/', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'})

reg = re.search(r'<br>([\w\s]+)<br><br>', r.text).group(1)
print(reg)
```